# Spring custom validator class with MultipartFile class support does not get called/fired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Sorry i couldn't find a better way to construct the question.

I am trying to validate on server side an array of multipartfile received with other information (e.g email, phone number etc) from an Ajax multipart/form-data post request.
I created 2 custom validator classes by implementing Spring Validator interface, `UserFilesValidator` to check that all received files are image files and are not above 2MB
and `UserInfosValidator` to check other user information e.g. phone number validate, email avalibility etc.
I registered the custom validator classes using `@InitBinder`.

Now when request is made, `UserInfosValidator` gets called and works fine but `UserFilesValidator` doesn't get called

Here is my code

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class UserController{

    private final UserFilesValidator userFilesValidator;
    private final UserInfosValidator userInfosValidator;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserFilesValidator userFilesValidator, UserInfosValidator userInfosValidator){
        this.userFilesValidator = userFilesValidator;
        this.userInfosValidator = userInfosValidator;
    }

    @InitBinder("userfiles")
    public void formDataBinder1(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.addValidators(userFilesValidator);
    }

    @InitBinder("userinfos")
    public void formDataBinder2(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.addValidators(userInfosValidator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<UserEntity> addUser(@RequestParam("userfiles") @Valid MultipartFile[] files,
                                                            @RequestPart("userinfos") @Valid UserEntity user){
        //codes ...
    }

}
```

Validator class

```
@Component
public class UserFilesValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MultipartFile[].class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        MultipartFile[] files = (MultipartFile[]) target;
    //validation codes ...
}

}
```

I excluded `UserInfosValidator` class since it works fine.
I also did not included global exception handler class (that's `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class) 
since errors has to be registered in `UserFilesValidator` class which is not even getting called.

So please how can i get this to work? I know i can validate it in `addUser` method but I don't want to have validation codes in controller class 
request handler method.